# Turbo C++ 4.5 error "undefined symbol owlmain..."

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I know Turbo C++ is ancient, but my daughter's school uses it, and I have to help her.

I am using Turbo C++ 4.5 in a Windows 7 Virtual Machine, which is running inside Windows 8.1.

For any project, when clicking "Build all", it gives the error:

```
"Undefined symbol OwlMain (int, char far*, far*) in library file c:\tcwin45\lib\owlwi.lib in module winmain"
```

I even created a new project with just one source file with the minimal code as follows:

```
void main () {
    // return;
}
```

Even then, I get the same error as above.

I don't understand the reason for this error. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ugh.  Don't link libraries that you are not using.

Comment: @HansPassant Unless you are joking I disagree. This question is useful and clear. Even if it will be hard to find anyone still using Turbo C++. Then again, if you don't find one here, where else?

Comment: I didn't use that version, but it sounds like you have selected an OWL project, so your main function would need to be OwlMain.  OWL is a framework for developing GUI applications.  If you do not want to write an OWL app then choose a different project type. It might be called "console" or something.

Comment: BTW it should be `int main() { }`. Having main return void is a non-standard extension.

Comment: Probably some library which shouldn't be linked. Did you check this [_thread_](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/borland.public.cpp.owl/UX8vyGv1hwg/QGvJX2WnbZsJ) ? (Link given just for sake of your daughter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that you are pulling in the OWL library (a library for creating GUIs). This probably means that you created your project with the wrong type. You need a simple, bare-bones console project.

Also, your school is doing your daughter a massive disservice by teaching outdated technology and (probably) methods. C++ has changed a lot since that compiler, and so the material she learns will only be partially applicable in the real world. You should consider raising a complaint.

Comment: C++ has not only "changed a lot"; C++ as we understand the term today (that is, ISO/IEC 14882) did not even _exist_ at the time that the OP's compiler was released. Think about all the other things which were different in the world in 1994 and you'll soon see just how serious this is.